# How do I only fill part of an object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill

I have an illustration that someone else created in Illustrator. I need to be able to choose the exact point in which to fill half of the shape with one color and the other half with another color? How do I do this? I guess something like how you could mask something in Photoshop so you couldn't edit that part while making changes to another part.

I'm not sure if 'illustration' or 'shape' is the right word to use because I have no experience with Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

I would cheat. Add points at the halfway mark, break it into two shapes, close each shape, and fill them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Often it is easiest to simply Copy then use Edit > Paste in Front and change the top object.